# Initial-scale=1 doesn't fix media query for iPad 2

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I have an issue with the iPad 2 where it is not applying the right styles from my media queries, even though I've included the following meta tag in the head of my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Here is my media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
... styles
}
```

I tripled checked to be certain that there weren't any styles overriding the ones that I had specified.  There were not.  It seems like the iPad's actual resolution is just slightly higher than 1024 x 768.

To work around the issue, I changed the initial scale and maximum-scale to 1.0025, which zoomed it in just a bit to make my media queries work, but this isn't exactly a perfect solution.

If the iPad 2's resolution is 1024 x 768 than why wouldn't setting the viewport's initial scale to 1 fix any issues with my media queries that are set-up to work at 1024 x 768?

Here are just a few of the articles I've read trying to figure this out (just for proof of research):

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

[Visual viewport vs Layout viewport on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344886/visual-viewport-vs-layout-viewport-on-mobile-devices)

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html