# Make zoom behavior on touch devices more like on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently running into an issue where a site I'm working on doesn't play nicely with the way mobile devices can zoom in.

Basically there is a horizontal full-width line on that website that is fixed and centered vertically and in the background is a long text. The page is automatically scrolling and the horizontal line tells the user which text-line is of importance right now. (The page automatically scrolls so that the important text line is in the center of the screen.)

But when I zoom in on my Android phone using Firefox, the line is not centered on the screen anymore. It's even possible to zoom in to the point that the line is not on the screen anymore at all. The page will still scroll automatically even in that case and I'm sure the important text is still under that horizontal line, but it's useless when it's not visible on the screen anymore.

On a normal desktop computer this problem doesn't exist. If you zoom in the horizontal line remains in its fixed position centered on the screen.

Now I'm wondering, is it possible to modify the zoom behavior in a way that it doesn't break my site on touch devices?

I know that I could disable zooming all together, but I don't just want to take that functionality away.
Also changing the font size instead of zooming wouldn't work because then the site wouldn't scroll to the correct position anymore.

Edit: Disabling zoom is not an option, even it it just disabled on touch devices. So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page) doesn't help.

Edit2: Here's a very simplified version of my code:

```js
$(function() {
    var textEl = $('#text');
    var $w = $(window);
    var percentPos = 0.000;
    
    setInterval(function() {
        var currentPosX = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
        var newPosY = textEl.offset().top-$w.height()/2+percentPos*textEl.height();
        window.scrollTo(currentPosX, newPosY);
        
        percentPos += 0.001;
        if (percentPos >= 1)
            percentPos = 0.000;
    }, 100);
    
})
```

```css
#line {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffef011f;
    height: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}

#text {
    color: #000;
    font: normal 12px/1.5 Courier New,monospace,Courier;
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line"></div>
<div id="container">
    <span id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.

    </span>
<div>
```

To run it on a mobile device you can click here: https://jsfiddle.net/k754fb1p/embedded/result

(In reality a server is handling the scroll position and just sends the percentual position to the client via websockets.)
But you can see that if you zoom in on a desktop device the yellow line remains on the same text line and the yellow line stays in center. On my Android phone with Firefox it doesn't:

[image: phone]

Comment: @Justinas No I don't want to take the ability to zoom away from the user.

Comment: So maybe try showing us your code?

Comment: Okay, I added a very simplified version of my code.

Comment: Again, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page does not answer my question. Please reopen or provide a proper reason for closing.

Comment: On a desktop, the zoom is focused on the middle. On touch devices, you can zoom by pinching on other places, like the top left-hand corner. If one zooms on the top left-hand corner, will the line remain visible on touch devices?

Comment: The line will remain on the middle of the page so if you zoom in on the top/left corner the line won't be visible anymore. If you only zoom in a bit, then it may still be visible, but not centered anymore.

Comment: I see. So by making zoom behavior on touch devices more like on desktop, do you mean only allowing zoom on the center section of the site (thus, altering the behavior such that zooming in on the top left-hand corner = zooming in on the centermost section, and causing the yellow line **and** the important text to remain visible)?

Comment: Yes either like this. Or simply like on desktop where viewport remains the same and the page gets scaled.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because of the way zoom works in different devices:

- In desktops, zooming effectively changes `devicePixelRatio`. From the perspective of the website, the rendering window becomes smaller.
- In mobile devices, it gets complicated: Zomming with two fingers changes the visible parts of the page, without affecting the layout of the content. Think about it like this:

  > Imagine the layout viewport as being a large image which does not change size or shape. The portion of the large image that you can see through the frame is the visual viewport. You can back away from the large image while holding your frame (zoom out) to see the entire image at once, or you can move closer (zoom in) to see only a portion.
  >   From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333966/9253414).

The problem with changing the visual viewport in this case is that it doesn't change the scroll position. It still follows the layout viewport, which scrolls, though.

This is not an easy problem to fix.

---

**UPDATE**

There is a way of getting information about the visual viewport position and scale through the [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API). You can center the line by changing its coordinates relative to `window.visualViewport.offsetTop`.

---

It's not recommended to disable zoom because of accessibility concerns, so you could replace the visual viewport zoom with custom code that simply changes the `font-size`, though I believe that would require listening to touch events, finding the distance between two touch points, etc...

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the user can't zoom normally on mobile from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page) with this meta tag:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

Then, you'll have to add an event listener to change of the browser's zoom from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript):

```
(function(){
  // Poll the pixel width of the window; invoke zoom listeners
  // if the width has been changed.
  var lastWidth = 0;
  function pollZoomFireEvent() {
    var widthNow = jQuery(window).width();
    if (lastWidth == widthNow) return;
    // Length changed, user must have zoomed, invoke listeners.
    if(widthNow < lastWidth) doDesktopZoomIn();
    else doDesktopZoomOut();
    lastWidth = widthNow;
  }
  setInterval(pollZoomFireEvent, 100);
})();
```

And finally, do a 'Desktop' zoom as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093570/force-page-zoom-at-100-with-js):

```
var scale = 1;

function doDesktopZoomIn() {
    scale += 0.25;
    var scaleCSS = 'scale(' + scale  + ')';
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
    document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
    document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General
}

function doDesktopZoomOut() {
    scale -= 0.25;
    var scaleCSS = 'scale(' + scale  + ')';
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
    document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
    document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/yLc8xsm9/3/embedded/result