# Open webpage, then click at coordinates in background

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to simulate an open webpage then send a mouse click at a certain set of coordinates.

I'm wanting this event to take place in the background without actually opening a browser or moving the mouse.

for example, open www.google.com and click submit(as a set of coordinates) without actually opening the site on the screen

Is this even possible?

Edit: site may also contain javascript

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this could help:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this is the direction I need to head. I need to edit my original post because I need it to handle java script.

Comment: [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is a library for automating browsers. You can run the browser in headless mode as mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).
You'll need to download the [Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) webdriver to start off.

Here's an example skeleton:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

# go to the google
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# click stuff using xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lst-ib"]').click()

# click stuff using coordinates
elem = find_element_by_selector(selector)
ac = ActionChains(browser)
ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(x_off, y_off).click().perform()

driver.quit()
```

[ActionChains API code courtesy of Dirk Bergstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775351/clicking-at-coordinates-without-identifying-element)