# Single click on a web page using cursor coordinates using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

Can any one help me to click on a web page using cursor coordinates using vba. I don't want to click either on button or any link. I want single click somewhere in between  tag using co-ordinates. But when i run web page on IE that time IE is minimized.How it can be done.

Comment: Checkout the selenium webdriver (for VBA) and then have a look there [Clicking at coordinates without identifying element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775351/clicking-at-coordinates-without-identifying-element)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks .can I get other solution other than selenium. I am not aware of selenium

Comment: I don't know of any solution with IE, guess it is not possible. IE is end of life anyway so it might be worthy to invest some time into the more powerful selenium.

Comment: What can you achieve by clicking on a webpage using co-ordinates than cannot be achieved by actually using the DOM?

Comment: @QHarr  I'm not achieving anything with this but I unfortunately my other functionality work if i click like this