# Excel vba selenium - Clicking Coordinates

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I'm trying to write a tool that will click a specific co-ordinate on a webpage.

There's no elements for me to identify, it's all images (I'm assuming flash or something)

I found this page

[Clicking at coordinates without identifying element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775351/clicking-at-coordinates-without-identifying-element/42152313)

Which suggests using ActionChains, and looks to be exactly what I want to do.
However the page seems to be for writing in python (Below is the code from that page, that I'm trying to replicate)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_by_offset(X coordinates, Y coordinates).click().perform()
```

And I can't figure out how to do the equivalent in VBA

Answer (score 0):

In VBA we do something like this :

```
driver.Actions.MoveByOffset(offset_x, offset_y).Perform
```

[Read the official Selenium VBA wrapper - GitHub](https://github.com/danwagnerco/selenium-vba/blob/master/wrapper/Actions.cs)

This is the internal implementation :

```
Public Function MoveByOffset ( 
    offsetX As Integer,
    offsetY As Integer
) As Actions
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go