# Clicking Checkbox Element on Website with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click an element on a website but can't find any way of identifying it.

The element is shown here (highlighted in blue):

[image]

For example, this does not work but for some reason does not raise an error:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ew--26811263891"))).click()
```

The element can be found on this page https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/kempton/19:00/winner  by first clicking on the box in the grid with header PaddyPower and row label Sharesa.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see on the design that it's a custom checkbox, I think the problem might be you should actually be clicking on the outermost element or, by looking at your screenshot, clicking on the `label` that you highlighted should work too.

Comment: Thanks @lucaswxp I've tried all sorts but just can't get it to work. None of these have worked: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='ew--26811514266']")("//label[@for='ew--26811514266']")
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_3yz7L6']//div[@class='_2S_LCT']"))).click()
            #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_3geHA9']//div[@class='_3yz7L6']"))).click()
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_3yz7L6']"))).click()`

Comment: @Andy Try getting the coordinates (x,y) of the element, selenium has a method for that or you can hardcode the coordinates yourself looking at devtools just for testing. Then you can perform a click operation on that exact coordinate: check here how https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637548/786418