# Getting current DOM object that touchmove or touchend is over

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

As Mozilla states on the [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/TouchEvent) page:

> The event's target is the same element  that received the touchstart
> event corresponding to the touch point, even if the touch point has
> moved outside that element.

This is not the same as `mousemove` and `mouseup`, where the target really is the DOM element that the mouse is over.

What's the best way, without using any library, to get the element that my `touchmove` or `touchend` event occurs on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the coordinates ([`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX) and [`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageY)) from the event object. Then use [`document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) to get the top element at that position.

Comment: `pageX` and `pageY` are properties of a [`Touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch) object, which is an element in a `TouchList`, which is the [`TouchEvent.touches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/TouchEvent.touches) property.

Comment: ... which does not exist in some browsers (i.e.: chrome for Android).

Comment: Maybe you mean [`clientX` and `clientY` rather than `pageX` and `pageY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74946571/5231110), respectively. See also [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39053913/5231110).