# Javascript onfocus not supporting `event` as an argument?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get current **X** and **Y** position of the cursor in the browser when I click or focus on some of the html elements. When I do this with `onclick` it worked. But with `onfocus` it didn't. Please see the examples below..

Working code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function findXCoord(evt) {
    if (evt.x)  return evt.x; 
    if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX; 
}

function findYCoord(evt) {
    if (evt.y) return evt.y; 
    if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY; 
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a onclick="alert('The x coordinate is: ' + findXCoord(event) + ' and the y coordinate is: ' + findYCoord(event));">Hi</a>
</body>
```

But when I change **onclick to onfocus**, It didn't show the x,y positions

(onclick="alert.... to onfocus="alert.......)

Comment: I want to know how events works with 'onfocus'

Comment: I know what you're asking. You said "But when I change onclick to onfocus, It didn't show the x,y positions" and I want to know what it **did** show. If something isn't working as you expect/want it to, you need to tell us what is currently happening so we can help you.

Comment: Also, I'm not even sure `focus` is a valid event for an `<a>` tag.

Comment: When I use onfocus, It alert nothing and no error also.

Comment: Dunno why Tim Down deleted his answer, I think it was correct. Focus is a [UI event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-UIEvent), there are no coordinates associated with it. You can get the event target (element) and get its coordinates though. Click is a [mouse event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent), and they do have coordinates.

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to place href tag, though it won't return you co-ordinate except i.e. but it will fire the event http://jsbin.com/irexog/edit#preview working solution.

And ya onfocus is supported by the anchor.

you need to modify the event handling specific to browser like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: I get like this, "The x coordinate is: undefined and the y coordinate is: undefined"

Comment: The x coordinate is: undefined and the y coordinate is: undefined

Comment: and did you tried using screenx/y? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y

Answer (score 0):

"onfocus" is not a mouse event, you can get mouse position only from mouse events.

You can use "onmouseover" if you really need it.