# Image showing different coordinates on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I am plotting an image of fixed width and height. I am allowing the user to click on the image - and storing the location (x-y coordinates) where the image was clicked. Here is a sample code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    var posx; var posy;

 function showP(e) {
        // captures the mouse position
        posx = 0; posy = 0;
        if (!e) { var e = window.event; }
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
            posx = e.clientX;
            posy = e.clientY;
        }
        alert('X mouse is: ' + posx + ' Y mouse is: ' + posy );
    } 
</script>
```

I am noticing that for a fixed point on the image, I am getting different X and Y coordinates on different browsers.

Can anyone tell why this is the case.
Thanks

Comment: Hard to say without seeing HTML/CSS it could be you have page certain element properties (border, margin, padding, etc.) rendering differently on the page across browsers, resulting in different X,Y positions.

Comment: Anyway you should first compute values relative to image element position.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y

Comment: Its a simple html as  <img src=".\image.jpg" width="200" height="200" onclick="showP(event)"/>

Comment: Thanks Anton, but I want a way so that these values do not change, irrespective of which browser or monitor user is working on.

Comment: @gunnerz Different browsers has different default values for margin and padding. If you don't set them the image will not be placed at the same place. You could set an absolute position on the image, or (better) get the offset of the image and subtract that from the coordinates you got, so you have local coordinates of the image.

Answer (score 1):

you can check all data that you get in your event

```
 var a = "";
 for (var key in e){ 
     if( typeof e[key]!='function' &&  typeof e[key] !='object' )
     a += key+'='+ e[key]+'\n' 
  }
  alert(a)
```

this constraction helps you compare margin and padding in browsers

```
var padding = parseInt($("#imgId").css("padding-top"));
```

I think you need investigate you code and styles, maybe you have some conflict with padding and margins that influences on you result.

Hope this way helps you.