# Image Map with popups on hover

Tags: javascript, hover, mouseover, imagemap

I've put together this responsive animated gif with popups using the hotspots on an image map.

https://my.stackpixel.com/Panasonic-gif.html

I used the following resources to get me this far.

[Image Map with Image popup on hover over hotspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152681/image-map-with-image-popup-on-hover-over-hotspot)
http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html#buttercup

It works fairly well but I have three issues.

1. I need to convert to click events versus hover on touch devices
2. I need to be able to position the popups accurately so they are always over the main image - position the popup differently for each popup.
3. The javascript code is severely redundant for the firing of the popups - sure there is a cleaner way.