# Changing text with position change of mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a script which I want to put in my html website. What this script does is that it changes text with change in mouse cursor position. For eg. if user is on (x,y)=(1,1) then some text will be displayed while if on (x,y)=(2,2) some other random text will be displayed.

```
var text = [ 'I am human.']
```

I am not sure about how to connect this to a mouse event. Like if pointer moves, display any random text from list of text. Can anyone provide the code? Will really help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery, you can just use the [mouse move function](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) and if you want effects, you can use JQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Javascript:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
   var randText = text[Math.floor(Math.random()*text.length)];
   var div = $("#textDiv");
   div.stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 100, function(){
       $(this).html(randText);
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, 100);
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="textDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You! By the way, is there any way to slow down the change? As in some effect like 'fade in' text? :)

Comment: I added example fading effects for you

Answer (score 2):

Bind `mousemove` on `window` or something, then use the [`screenX` / `screenY` / `clientX` / `clientY` / etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y) on the event object.

A simple demo:

```
var $message = $('#message');

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(e.clientX > e.clientY) {
        $message.text('top right triangle');
    } else {
        $message.text('bottom left triangle');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="message">Move the mouse.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qjtnd/

Comment: Although one of the tags was jquery, I don't think jquery is necessary in this case, it's easily accomplishable without it, but if he wants to use jquery it's his choice. +1 for good answer.

Comment: How can I bind the function with every pixel rather than (e.clientX > e.clientY), I want that random text from 'var Text' is displayed if the mouse is moved even a pixel? Thanks for the answer though :D

Comment: @Dvorak, just remove the `if else`, and put in `$message.text(text[~~(Math.random() * text.length)]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = [ 'I am human.'
            , 'Some text here.'
            , 'I love technology.'
            , 'You are a good person'
            ]
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
   var randomItem = text[Math.floor(Math.random()*text.length)];
    alert(randomItem);
});
```

See at http://jsfiddle.net/2raaa/

Comment: Seeing that he wants it to change on every pixel movement, using alert could be rather annoying/problematic.  It would be better to either use Console.log or print out within some div.

Comment: Ya sure.But he can do this simple task now.