# Make an element fade in when visible in browser view and fade out when not

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I've been playing around with the jquery plugin waypoints. I would like to have this element fade in when is browser view and fade out when not but I haven't been able to figure it out. The element I'm using is an  with position: absolute. I'm not sure whether that will effect the script or not.

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LvjoLuvx/2/ on what I'm working with. waypoints.js is linked in the external resources.

HTML

```
<li id="span">

    <img class="logo"></img>

</li>
```

CSS

```
#span{
    height: 2000px;
    list-style: none;
}

.logo{
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.logo').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    // Fade in here
    $(this).fadeIn(800);
}, {
   offset: function() {
       // The bottom of the element is in view
       return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
    }
});
```

Comment: I see no point in hiding something that can't be seen

Comment: @Dale Hiding might be relevant so that your pages vertical size gets smaller but the fade effect is meaningless if the user can not see it :)

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335517/1876355 then you will understand how to see whether something is in view point (visible to the user) or not, then google something like `get Element top left corner`, after that, When you have the points (And the width) of the element, you can simply do an if statement to see if you can hide the element or not.

Comment: @ Dale It's so I can have all the elements I want fade-in at whatever point I want.