# Html5-canvas- How to remove space between the point I click and the draw point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

please see the image below for better understanding what I mean :

http://8pic.ir/images/c6kzf0n0eu1v81sv3lit.jpg

as you can see, I scrolled down and when I click on canvas to point a position , it gives space between the point I click and the point it draw the line .

this is my code:

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw,ch;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var nameimageis =1;


// set some canvas styles
ctx.strokeStyle='black';

// an array to hold user's click-points that define the clipping area
var points=[];

// load the image 
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="http://localhost/image/D0D70A02A7_166.18K_{}_6458.JPG";

function start(){

  // resize canvas to fit the img
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;

  // draw the image at 25% opacity
  drawImage(1);

  // listen for mousedown and button clicks
  $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $('#reset').click(function(){ points.length=0; drawImage(1); });
}


    rightclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(!e.offsetX) {
        e.offsetX = (e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left);
        e.offsetY = (e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top);
      }
      var x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i+=2) {
        dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - points[i], 2) + Math.pow(y - points[i+1], 2));
        if ( dis < 6 ) {
          points.splice(i, 2);
          draw();
          record();
          return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    };

function handleMouseDown(e){

  // tell the browser that we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // calculate mouseX & mouseY
  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // push the clicked point to the points[] array
  points.push({x:mx,y:my});

  // show the user an outline of their current clipping path
  outlineIt();

  // if the user clicked back in the original circle
  // then complete the clip
  /*if(points.length>1){
    var dx=mx-points[0].x;
    var dy=my-points[0].y;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<10*10){
      clipIt();
    }
  }*/
}


// redraw the image at the specified opacity
function drawImage(alpha){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.globalAlpha=alpha;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
}

// show the current potential clipping path
function outlineIt(){
  drawImage(1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(points[0].x,points[0].y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

How can I remove this space and point the right position every where I clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `e.clientY` in function `handleMouseDown`. clientX/Y is relative to the viewport, not the document. Try use `e.pageX/Y`, which are relative to the document content.

More details in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y).