# javascript selected text is not properly positioned after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to let my user to search by selecting text. After selecting text, a new button open on right of the selected text for giving an option to search or not. when user scroll to bottom on the page, search button is not properly positioned. My code is given below:

**html:**

```
 <body ng-app="newsApp"  ng-controller="NewsCtrl" ng-mouseup="showSelectedText($event)">  

     <!-- user search button -->
     <div ng-show="isUserSearch" ng-style="{ 'left' : leftPos, 'top': rightPos, 'display': displayState }" class="searchBtn">
        Search             
     </div>

     <!-- main content -->
     <div>
       <!-- main content -->
    </div>

 </body>
```

**css::**

```
.searchBtn {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    color: #ddd;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

**javascript::**

```
angular.module('newsApp',  [])

   .controller('NewsCtrl',function ($scope) {

       $scope.leftPos = "-200px";
       $scope.rightPos = "-200px";
       $scope.displayState = "none !important";
       $scope.isUserSearch = false;

       $scope.selectedTextSearch = "";

       $scope.showSelectedText = function($event) {
          $scope.selectedText =  "";

          if (window.getSelection) {
             $scope.selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
          } 
         else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
             $scope.selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
          }

          if($scope.selectedText.length > 0)    {            
             $scope.leftPos = (+$event.clientX + 5) + 'px';   
             $scope.rightPos = ( +$event.clientY - 15 ) + 'px';  
             $scope.isUserSearch = true;
          } else {
             $scope.isUserSearch = false;
          }
       };

   });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HvajAkKKg1u335eUUzxs?p=preview)

What can I do now?

Comment: could you create a plunkr/fiddle of the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `clientX` to `pageX`

```
$scope.leftPos = (+$event.pageX + 5) + 'px';   
$scope.rightPos = ( +$event.pageY - 15 ) + 'px';
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335517/2407212) for the difference.