# onmousemove returns different value over elements with z-index

Tags: javascript, z-index, heatmap, onmousemove

I am trying to display a heatmap of where the user moved their mouse on a screen (using a Chrome extension). I'm using a library called [heatmap.js](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) to handle this.

More specifically, I am using this as an example -- https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-mousemove-heatmap.html

My problem is that the site I wish to display this heatmap on is making heavy use of `z-index`. The issue with this is that when you mouseover an element with a `z-index` other then `auto`, the value returned by `onmousemove` is not what one would expect -- instead of the value of the mouse on the screen, some other value relative to the top left of the screen is returned.

You can see this in action here -- https://jsfiddle.net/rj870o6c/

To counteract this, I tried adding an overlay div on top of the entire page with a `z-index` of `9999`. This works, but then I lose the ability to interact with the page below, and of course, I can not use `pointer-events: none;` since I need to capture the value of the mouse.

You can see this in action here (try clicking the link in the yellow box, it won't work) -- https://jsfiddle.net/ktwbbpbn/

Is there a way to get the real value of the mouse pointer when hovering over elements that have a `z-index`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was that I was using `layerX` and `layerY` for grabbing the position of the mouse. That's a bad idea for my use case because that only returns data relative to the current layer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX). The answer is to use `pageX` and `pageY` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y) for more info.

For anyone who might find this useful, here's a JSFiddle with everything working as expected -- https://jsfiddle.net/h1us1syr/