# e.screenY giving wrong value (mouse coordinates)

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, coordinates, mouselistener

I'm having trouble getting the Y mouse coordinates.

```
function mouseDistance() {
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = e.screenX + " " + e.screenY;
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    mouseDistance();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

`e.screenX` is working properly, but `e.screenY` isn't. In the html body, at the top most edge it doesn't get lower than 95px (shouldn't it be 0?).

I do have a 'CSS reset'.

Example: The mouse at the top left corner will be at x: 0; y: 95;

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y

Comment: :o thanks. Can't upvote your comment :P // should I delete?

Comment: Nope, leave it there, it's OK. I've provided a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `screenY` provides the vertical coordinate (offset) of the mouse pointer in **global (screen) coordinates**.

The property you probably want to use is the `clientY`, which returns the vertical coordinate within the application's client area at which the event occurred.

> For example, clicking in the top-left corner of the client area will always result in a mouse event with a clientY value of 0, regardless of whether the page is scrolled vertically.