# Difference between 'x' and 'clientX' property of event in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is difference between 'x' and 'clientX' property of 'event' object in javascript?

In the Below Code. I tried to diffrentiate between 'x' and 'clientX' property of event object but i am getting value for 'x' and 'clientX' in console.

```html
<html>
<head><title>event property </title>
<script language="javascript">
function detect(e){
   console.log("event is fired on "+e.currentTarget.id+" X="+e.x+" Y="+e.y+" offsetX="+e.offsetX+" offsetY="+e.offsetY+" clientX="+e.clientX+" clienty="+e.clientY+" screenX="+e.screenX+" screenY="+e.screenY);
   
}



</script>
 </head>
<body onclick="detect(event);" id="body">
<div onclick="detect(event);" id="parent-div" style="position:fixed; top:10px; left:10px; width:400; height:400px; border:2px; border-style:solid;  border-color:red; "> 
<div onclick="detect(event);"  id="div" style ="width:300px; height:300px; position:fixed; top:100px; left:100px;  border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color: black;  ">


<img id="image" src="photo1.jpg" onclick="detect(event);" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:relative; top:50px; left: 50px; border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:purple;"/>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is 'x' is same as 'clientX'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MouseEvent.x property is an alias for the MouseEvent.clientX property. See MDN docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/x