# How to calculate left and top for div with position absolute when click

Tags: javascript, css

I have some items with "click" event. When I click on this items I have to show modal in the place of the click. This modal has position absolute.

I try to get event.pageX and event.pageY

```
let style = 'top: ' + event.pageX+ 'px; left: ' + event.pageY + 'px;';
```

but my modal shows very far (look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/brRa073u7J73vA

Comment: What are you passing as the `event`?

Comment: set parent position relative and modal with position absolute in the parent

Comment: event is a click

Comment: if i set parent position relative my modal turns out even further

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clientX`/`clientY` event's properties to get the place of the click

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `clientX` and `clientY`, and not `pageX` and `pageY`. Also, notice that you must put `position: absolute` on the modal you're trying to place so it'll work as you're expecting it to (and if you're not too familiar with positioning you should definitely read about it - it's not as simple as it sounds).

> **`pageX`** and **`pageY`**:
>
> Relative to the top left of the fully rendered content area in the browser [...] **This point could be anywhere in the browser window and can actually change location if there are embedded scrollable pages embedded within pages and the user moves a scrollbar.**
>
> **`screenX`** and **`screenY`**:
>
> Relative to the top left of the physical screen/monitor.
>
> **`clientX`** and **`clientY`**:
>
> **Relative to the upper left edge of the content area (the *viewport*)** of the browser window. This point does not move even if the user moves a scrollbar from within the browser.

Read more:

- [What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y#answer-9335517)

Here's a working example:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.style.top = e.clientY+"px";
    modal.style.left = e.clientX+"px";
});
```

```css
#modal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem when I use clientX and clientY http://joxi.ru/v29L590SZ3ZXDm

Comment: @Viktor I don't see your code so I can't really tell you what's wrong - but I've added a working example as inspiration to help you figure out what went wrong. Do notice that you must use `position: absolute` to properly place the modal.

Comment: @Viktor what browser and version are you using?

Comment: @raphael75 @NonameSL I`ve created new theme with detailed description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738492/how-to-calculate-left-and-top-for-vue-component-with-position-absolute-when-clic