# changing position relative to mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cursor-position

I looked for many similar question but couldn't solve my issue. *Here I have pasted only a single list item out of my code*. I need to create a `span` on `mousemove` event over the `list` item, and set its **left-offset** from its parent as the mouse moves. As I haven't ever tried any such thing, I experimented a lot with the code to get to this-

```js
document.querySelector("li a").addEventListener("mousemove",(event)=> {

   let span;
   let alreadyHasSpan =    event.target.hasChildNodes().length > 1; //default length=1

   if(!alreadyHasSpan) {
    span = $(`<span class="a-effect"></span>`);
    span.appendTo(event.target);
   }

   let targetLeftPos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    span.css("left",`${event.clientX-targetLeftPos}px`);


   $(this).mouseleave(function () { 
    span.remove();
   });
}, false);
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}
.a-effect {
 position: absolute; left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 2%;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="nav-item active">
  <a href="/" class="nav-link">Product</a> 
</li>
```

On my browser, the `span` moves but with **trailing signs** behind it-

[image]

Apart from the trailing signs, it oftens misses to show the `span`. On this question's snippets, it's even worse to show the issue.

What's the issue and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, the issue is that you're adding a new span everytime the mouse moves. I am guessing you only want to add it when mouse enters, and remove it once the mouse leaves.

I have tried to keep your code as much as possible and change only what is causing your issue.

```js
document.querySelector("li a").addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {

  let span;
  let alreadyHasSpan = event.target.childNodes.length > 1; //default length=1

  if (!alreadyHasSpan) {
    span = $(`<span class="a-effect"></span>`);
    span.appendTo(event.target);
  }
});

document.querySelector("li a").addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  let targetLeftPos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  if (event.target.childNodes.length > 1) {
    let span = event.target.childNodes[1];
    $(span).css("left", `${event.clientX-targetLeftPos}px`);
  }
});

document.querySelector("li a").addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
  if (event.target.childNodes.length > 1) {
    let span = event.target.childNodes[1];
    span.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}

.a-effect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="nav-item active">
  <a href="/" class="nav-link">Product</a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for making it the same way I wanted! By the way, as @Lapskaus used ````pageX```` in his answer, is it still fine for me to use ````clientX````.  His answer made me search for ````pageX```` after which I think I should use ````pageX```` in this context. what do you think?

Comment: That is out of my scope of knowledge. But, if it ain't broke, don't fix it?

Comment: if you want, here's what I found for my search- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335517/12997674. Btw I thought I'm the least knowledgeable person on the planet. :)

Comment: You will still most likely get a jumping effect at the start that way, since you do not calculate the `spans` position in your `mouseenter` event,but only in your `mousemove`.

Comment: Technically true, but i have not been able to see the jump. (Multiple mousemove events have already fired as the mouse enters, because the mouse is moving as it enters.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure where you want to place your span element but there are some problems in your code that i would correct first. The placement of the element is relatively easy to change then.

Firstly, you append the span element in a mousemove function and them check everytime that event triggers, if the span is already there. Change that to use the `mouseenter` event for the `span` creation.
Secondly, you add a new mouseleave handler for your link evetytime you move your mouse. Same as before, create that handler outside of your `mousemove` event.

Regarding the position of your elememt, I am not sure where you expect it to appear/follow your mouse but you can easily adapt the `offsetX` and `offsetY` variables in my `moveSpan()` function to adapt it to your needs.

Keep in mind when you are positioning the element, that the calculation is based off of the position of your `a` element.

```js
function moveSpan( e ) {
 let $el = $(e.target);
 let xPos = e.pageX;
  let yPos = e.pageY;
  let offsetX = $el.width() / 2;
  let offsetY = $el.height() / 2;
  let $span = $el.find('span');
  $span.css({
    'left': (xPos - offsetX) + 'px',
    'top': (yPos - offsetY) + 'px'
  });
}

$('li a').on('mouseenter', function( e ) {
 let span = $('<span />').addClass('a-effect');
  $(this).append( span );
  moveSpan( e );
}).on('mousemove', function( e ) {
 moveSpan( e );
}).on('mouseleave', function( e ) {
 $(this).find('span').remove();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
}

.a-effect {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">Product</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just searched for ````pageX```` vs ````clientX```` after I saw your code. Also, I actually wanted to move ````span```` inside ````a```` horizontally for which I set `````position: relative```` to ````a````. Thanks any way!