# clientX, pageX, screenX, offsetX, offsetLeft, movementX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the difference between these terms? I'm tangled up from last some days and can't understand the difference clearly. Highlight with examples?

Javascript!

clientX/clientY,

pageX/pageY,

screenX/screenY,

offsetX/offsetY,

offsetLeft/offsetTop,

movementX/movementY.

Comment: check the link  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Comment: I check it out weeks ago. But overall I'm confused. Like when to use specific one. It's fine to read separately but it becomes hard when it comes to making a difference and using by own.

Comment: at the beginning it takes some  time to  understand and keep in mind ..  I suggest to  you learn these from  youtube . I think  it should be help for you ..

Comment: Maybe give us a bit more context what confuses you about these properties. The documentation @AbdullahAlNoor posted is actually quite clear. Do you want to use them for something specific? Or just learning / curiosity? If so I recommend just building a simple demo and use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)