# div follow cursor based on parent div not pageY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can i get the div to follow the cursor not based on page height, the way i currently have it the div gets further away from the cursor as i scroll, i need it to stay with it at all times, i have tried a few things but none seem to work. here is a link to what i have made https://www.poshcloud.co.uk/posh-hero/

this is the function im using

```
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  const circle = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
  const left = e.pageX;
  const top = e.pageY;
  circle.style.left = left + 'px';
  circle.style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Use **clientX** and **clientY** instead of **pageX** and **pageY**.  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML structure, particularly where the cursor ball big lies within it. You probably need clientX etc but can’t be sure without knowing what the circle is placed within.

Comment: Thankyou client x and y did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `clientX` and `clientY`should solve your issue

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  const circle = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
  const left = e.clientX;
  const top = e.clientY;
  circle.style.left = left + 'px';
  circle.style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

```css
.cursor__ball--big {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor__ball--big"></div>
```