# Problem trying to centre image with touch events

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the problem I am facing is that I want to centre my image to the touch that will drag it. e.g. If the user touches the top right corner of the image, the image will automatically move so its centre is on that touch instead.

With the code

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX +"px";
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientX - shiftX +"px";
```

not working.

Here is the full code of the touch start event:

```
img.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
          beingDragged = img;
          start = e.target.parentNode.id;
          img.style.zIndex = 1;
          shiftX = e.touches[0].clientX-(img.width/2);
          shiftY = e.touches[0].clientY - (img.height/2);//code for dragging the image in the later touchmove event
          img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX +"px";
          img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY +"px";
        });
```

Note I have tried to remedy this problem with using the shift values used later in the touchmove event.

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - shiftX +"px";
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - shiftY +"px";
```

as well as using the the bounding client rectangle

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Both to no avail.

The touch move function works as intended just this minor problem with touchstart. Maybe I am being a bit nitty gritty here as the program works with touchscreens I just don't like this detail.

The image's css

```
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Edit:
Some images of it in my program to maybe help visualise, note the cursor illustrates the touch point.

This is what is currently happening if touchstart is on an edge

[image: img1]

I want it to be more central like so

[image: img2]

In response to Darryl's comment I tried to replicate this error on a smaller level but instead solved it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content=width=device-width,user-scalable=no>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let shiftX;
            let shiftY;
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Location_dot_blue.svg/1200px-Location_dot_blue.svg.png";
            img.style.position = "absolute";
            img.style.height = 99.016+"px";
            img.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
              start = e.target.parentNode.id;
              img.style.zIndex = 1;
            });
            img.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              img.style.left=e.touches[0].clientX-img.width/2+"px";
              img.style.top=e.touches[0].clientY-img.height/2+"px";
            });
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

But when moving this solution to the main code it flings the image of the screen.

Comment: Added some images to help

Comment: Is there any more improvements I can make?

Comment: Just to be sure, in your "touchstart" event listener, you are defining `shiftX` and `shiftY` but not using them, that's not the problem, is it?

Comment: Can you please include a [mre] in your question? You can make it into a runnable Snippet using Ctrl+M or the button in the toolbar (end of second group; the file-with-angle-brackets icon).

Comment: @M0nst3R yes that is the case

Comment: @DarrylNoakes  I have tried that and I found a soloution for it in the example but this soloution did not work in my main code. Im not sure of what next steps to take as I don't know what factor is making the main code different from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can try out and use. 2 implementations:

1. when you grab the image it stick to the cursor w/o centering on the click or move.
2. when you click/move image and the image is centered to the screen as you mentioned in your response

However you need to test it w/o `iframe` html elements as they sometimes do not give the best viewport info.

You can get code and test from the following links:

- https://h3lcw6.csb.app/ (code can be seen [here in the same sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-answer-to-77883324-h3lcw6) here you can open in a new window directly to see how it works w/o jumps as compare to other sandboxes
- https://gist.github.com/UtmostCreator/9f02bdad61dc9b99e72437fbf03d293e
- https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/k36h9fqx/

Using `img.onload` function we make sure that the touch event listeners are only added after the image is fully loaded in the `DOM` to our user. This guarantees that the dimensions and position of the image are accurately calculated for us and accounted for.

- `let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect()` get image's position and size on the screen. [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) returns an object with properties such as `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `width`, and `height` (size of the overall rectangle in pixels)
- `offsetX = e.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;` and `offsetY = e.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;` - to calculate the horizontal (`offsetX`) and vertical (`offsetY`) distance from the initial touch point to the top-left corner of the image (this way we maintain the touch point's position, when starting dragging)
- `img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - offsetX + "px";` and `img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - offsetY + "px";` - updates the  position of the image on the screen as we drag/move (top and left are set based on the current touch position minus the initially calculated offsets of the image)

```
// rect.left and rect.top give the X and Y coordinates of the top-left corner of the image relative to the viewport.
// e.touches[0].clientX - position of the cursor relative to the page
// deduction is done to calculate the offset between the initial touch point (where the user touched the image) and the top-left corner of the image's bounding box
```

[What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    let offsetX = null;
    let offsetY = null;
    let img = document.createElement("img");

    // Ensure the image is fully loaded before adding event listeners
    img.onload = function() {
        // drag and re-position image to center of the cursor
        img.onload = function() {
          img.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
            img.offsetX = rect.width / 2;
            img.offsetY = rect.height / 2;
            offsetX = img.offsetX;
            offsetY = img.offsetY;
            img.style.zIndex = 1;
          });
          // drag from the position you click:
          // img.onload = function () {
          //   img.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
          //     e.preventDefault();
          //     let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
          //     offsetX = e.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;
          //     offsetY = e.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;
          //     img.style.zIndex = 1;
          //   });

          img.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - offsetX + "px";
            img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - offsetY + "px";
          });
        };

        img.src =
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Location_dot_blue.svg/1200px-Location_dot_blue.svg.png";
        img.style.position = "absolute";
        img.style.height = "99.016px";
        document.body.appendChild(img);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```