# Mobile Optimisation: Site wrapper fills screen at 1000px even though iPhone 5s screen is 640px?

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries

I am altering a site to be mobile optimised. I am currently testing on an iPhone 5C whose screen width (in portrait mode) is 640px.

However, when I set my sites `#wrapper` to `width: 640px;` the site only takes up about half of the screen. I have to set it to `width: 1000px;` for it to fill the phones screen.

`#wrapper` is the parent element of all elements so there is nothing on the outside of it to push the site outside of 640px. There is also nothing within `#wrapper` that is larger then 640px and I have set `overflow:hidden` just to be sure.

Would anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do about it?

The Media Query I am using is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)" href="css/ios5.css"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must insert this tag into your html HEAD tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The reason is clearly explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary).