# Webpage is not resizing to fit the screen on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: html, ios8, safari, viewport, iphone-6-plus

I am facing a problem on this particular page. http://staging.creativewritingagency.com/contact-us.php

Now, this is not a responsive website. The client only requires that he should be able to view the complete page (without zooming in or out on the mobile screen) in first view. Later, he would pinch in and out to view and read the text.

So I did a bit of research and found that this can be done using viewport meta tag. I inserted the following code to `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

As per my knowledge, this code should

- set the width of webpage to device width
- set initial zoom level at 1.
- let the user perform zoom actions

However, this code seems to be working only on Chrome for Android. Safari browser on iPhone 6 Plus is still displaying full page. Here's a screenshot of what I see on emulated iPhone 6 Plus on Browserstack. http://prntscr.com/81vs1n

Could someone please look into it and point where I may be doing things the incorrect way.

P.S. This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am open to suggestions on improving the questioning format.

EDIT - Width of my web page is 1170px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I stumbled upon [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary) while reading more about viewport. Today I learned that viewport is used to normalize the built in zoom behavior.

Thanks @subodh for pointing me in that direction.

Now, I have updated my meta tag to read like this and it works like a charm.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1180">`

EDIT - Forgot to mention, I removed initial-scale from my actual code. It was causing the page to zoom to 100% original pixels, as a result of which, it had to be scrolled horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

The `width=device-width` is the issue.

It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%.

The width of the viewport in pixels. The default is 980. The range is from 200 to 10,000.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: Then what code should I put in head section so that it serves properly on all devices. Landscape or portrait.

Comment: Besides, if using `width=device-width` is the problem, then how come chrome on android is displaying the page as intended. :(

Comment: If your page is not responsive, that is what is wrong on IOS. Set it to your page width. Only you know the width since your created it. Do not ask people to do your work for you. <meta name="viewport" content="width=980, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">.

Answer (score 2):

Set fixed width in meta tag not according to device.

Comment: My page width is 1170px (the `<div>` with `class=container-nomb`).
So according to you, I should put this code in head section.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1170, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, maximum-scale=1">`

However, even this does not help. Rather, I don't see any change.

Comment: It was the initial state. Things were much better then. However, there was a horizontal scroll in that condition in iPhone. I'll show you the screen. http://prntscr.com/81wbri