# Mobile CSS file not loading

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, responsive

I'm using three separate style sheets with different media queries to load my site  suitably at various screen sizes, however I can't seem to get the mobile style sheet (max-width: 480px) to load at all. Instead it loads the (max-width: 1000px) style sheet.

Here's how they are presented in the html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/page_style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='/CSS/page_narrow.css' media='screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 481px)'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='/CSS/page_thin.css' media='screen and (max-width: 480px)'>
```

EDIT - I have just tried with the viewport meta tags and works. Thanks guys I'd been stuck on that for a few days now!

Comment: How are you testing your work? Are you using something like Chrome's device emulator?

Comment: You are using absolute paths, are you sure that "/CSS/page_style.css" is loaded correctly ?

Comment: Are you adding the [viewport meta tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary) to your document?

Comment: I agree with @Turnip, without viewport meta tag many mobile browsers simulate 980px-wide screen

Comment: I have tested the code myself; both with the viewport meta tag and without the tag. I can confirm that the stylesheet only loads for me when using the viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Writing because nobody took his time to post an answer.

The problem is unless [viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary) is added, mobile browsers simulate usually 980px wide displays, so they will load your stylesheet designed for 481-1000px.

Setting up `width=device-width` will make them use real device's screen width.

Complete code -  add to `<head>` following line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```