# IOS Safari Background Images Not Showing With @Media and CSS

Tags: html, css, safari

I have been working on a solution to the problem with no luck. I have a set of background images, a full size set for desktop and a mobile optimised set of images.

Now when I run the following code on Chrome on the desktop and resize the browser to activate the `@media` then everything runs great and looks correct. But when I then go to test on safari on the IPhone I just get a blank spot where the background image should be.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


section.box_park {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: url('/images/sample-park.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

section.box_building_management {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: url('/images/building-management.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {

    section.box_building_management {
        background: url('/images/mobile-building-management.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }

    section.box_park {
        background: url('/images/mobile-sample-park.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }

}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

*** UPDATE ***

If I comment out the @media it will display the background images but obviously not the mobile optimised ones.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add `width:` into your media side or at least height

Comment: Have you added a [viewport meta tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary) to the page?

Comment: Yes this is the code <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">