# Responsive CSS v. Chrome's Responsive View

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I'm working on a page template with a header at the top of the page. Nothing complex:

```
<div class="top-header">
text
</div>

.top-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

In Chrome, that produces what I expected...a bar across the top 50px high and as wide a my viewport. Resizing my browser changes with width, but not the height, which is fixed at 50px.

However, using Chrome's Developer Tools, I realized that when viewing in responsive mode, the header resizes vertically. In essence, there's a level of full-page zoom going on.

What key concept am I missing here? I assume it might be a zoom property on the body. How to I ensure that my header is 50px on *all* devices?

Screen shots:

[image]

Top is using Chrome's responsive mode, bottom is simply resizing Chrome to the same width not using responsive mode.

Comment: Did you add the viewport meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the viewport meta tag, to control the layout on mobile browsers.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26):

> Safari on iOS displays webpages at a scale that works for most web
>   content originally designed for the desktop. If these default settings
>   don’t work for your webpages, it is highly recommended that you change
>   the settings by configuring the viewport. You especially need to
>   configure the viewport if you are designing webpages specifically for
>   iOS. Configuring the viewport is easy—just add one line of HTML to
>   your webpage—but understanding how viewport properties affect the
>   presentation of your webpages on iOS is more complex. Before
>   configuring the viewport, you need a deeper understanding of what the
>   visible area and viewport are on iOS.

This other anwser does a very good job explaining why you need to specify it: [Is the viewport meta tag really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary)

Comment: Can you tell I'm a bit rusty? That's exactly it. 'doh! :) Thanks!