# Do we need <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> without Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, metadata

If we don't use Bootstrap do we need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in `<head>` of our HTML page?

Comment: Your sure do if you intend to support mobile! Otherwise your page will look very small upon loading. Checkout https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ or better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**YES**. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is completely unrelated to the Bootstrap framework, and should be on **every** webpage, regardless of what framework you're using.

The [**`viewport META tag`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) allows **[`device width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/device-width)** to map to the **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** CSS property, which essentially means that device pixels correctly map to CSS pixels, allowing elements and fonts to correctly scale on mobile devices. Without this, **[a pixel is not a pixel](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)** in the traditional sense.

Without the `viewport META tag`, you will have an incredibly hard time ensuring that your website looks the same across various different mobile devices, as most mobile devices have different viewports. Fonts may seem much too big on one device, and much too small on another, even when using percentage-based units of measurement. Apple has **[great documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)** showcasing this in Safari.

In addition to this, Google now audits websites for the `viewport META tag` through Lighthouse, and making use of it will [**improve your SEO**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/has-viewport-meta-tag):

[image]

To ensure that your website displays correctly on all mobile devices, make **sure** to use the `viewport META tag` with `content` containing either `width`, `initial-scale` or both. Also make use of **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** to fine-tune responsive designs.

CSS Tricks has **[a helpful list](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)** of breakpoints that kick in for **specific** devices, if you're looking for detailed mobile optimisation, and **[ViewportSizes](http://viewportsizes.com/)** has a sheet showcasing 286 different mobile devices and their respective viewport sizes for reference.