# HTML & CSS tables showing perfect in Android Firefox but not in Android Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This HTML and CSS content table displays perfectly in desktop chrome and firefox but when I open it in the android chrome browser the right side of the table was not showing properly but working perfectly in the android firefox browser. Everything working fine in chrome but only in the android 8.0 version. The problem is only in the android 10 version. Chrome is updated.

```
Check the HTML&CSS at codepen. 
 https://codepen.io/Zeeshanelahi/pen/GRrrNNv
```

[Firefox View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4sy4.png)
[Chrome view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrOeM.png)

Comment: Please provide all relevant code **in the question itself**, not only on an external site. Please also read the error messages provided to you and follow the advice given in them, rather than getting around them.

Comment: In which model are you testing ? I tested a Pixel Android 8 on browserstack.com and couldn't reproduce your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742580/do-we-need-meta-name-viewport-content-width-device-width-initial-scale-1-0/47742613

Comment: Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the `<head>` section of your html, and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

This issue of yours is mostly related to responsiveness. [Responsiveness](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) is a feature of web sites or web applications to get adapted on different displays (in terms of size) so the content of containers keep their initial position, size, attractiveness, etc.

In your case, without making your table responsive, you may fix the issue ONLY for particular moment (Android Chrome) and it will keep showing irrelevant behavior in other various browsers or displays.

Responsiveness is mostly made by assigning dynamyc values to sizing properties. Instead of giving certain static values, for example, with px, you should give more dynamic ones, such as percentage (%), rem, em, etc.

Please, consider this and try to approach your issue more globally by generally making it responsive so that you won't face any other this kind of issues. Hit me up if you need any more assistance.

P.S. Since I did not have enough rep., I couldn't leave a comment and had to post this as an answer.

Comment: I think you explained fluid designs, not responsive  so you got a downvote. See  https://link.medium.com/JcSmP2My5eb

Comment: Fluid-design is a part of responsive design, in general. To be precise, the main factor of fluid-design is an ability of responding to every single screen-size change which defines a responsive design. The articles hosted in Medium are mostly based on the personal opinion of an author which means can be biased.