# Background Image CSS resize issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am having troubles with elements size with CSS on mobile.

The background image have 853x480 px, that's supposed to fit perfectly I am wrong?

It's really very very simple CSS code, why that is going on?

Desktop Responsive view: https://prnt.sc/j7d1jr

On desktop browsers the page fit perfectly, the elements like background image and inputs displays perfectly.

On mobile all that resize, all smaller

Iphone mobile view: http://prntscr.com/j7d0ej

How to fix that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Banco BRB</title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("bg_login.png");
        background-color: red;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:  820px;
        height: 480px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <center><img src='user.png' height="75%" width="40%"></center>
    <br><br>
    <form>
        <center><label><input type="text"></label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: don't give a fixed width and height to your body and use background size cover or contain - mobile phones vary in size, there is no fixed dimensions.  Also center tag is obsolete and should not be used

Comment: Mobiles require a [viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary/14775557).

Comment: Check HTML code, here's a `<center>` tag alone

Comment: The second <center> tag is not closed. You are missing a </center>.

Also you are missing a closing </html> tag after </body>.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `<center>` now... it's 2018.