# Default virtualport size on mobile when meta tag is not declared?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Is it mandatory for responsive design the use of the meta tag viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

I have done few test without and it works well on desktops browser and it adapts propertly to the size of the windows, even if I use viewports as width or height to define header and footer.

So is that meta tag only useful to mobile devices or that's either necessary?
Does viewport use a default width or height for mobile devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the viewport meta tag really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When the meta tag is not defined* there is a virtual viewport default values defined. Non-mobile-optimized sites with these default vaules looks in general better on narrow screen devices.

On Safari iOS the **default width is 980 pixels**, and the others browsers width size are alike or a little less.

Narrow screen devices (e.g. mobiles) render pages in a virtual window or viewport, which is usually wider than the screen, and then shrink the rendered result down so it can all be seen at once. Users can then pan and zoom to see different areas of the page.

> For example, if a mobile screen has a width of 640px, pages might be rendered with a virtual viewport of **980px**, and then it will be shrunk down to fit into the 640px space.

[Explanation and default values for width and height with viewport on mobiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Apple as the inventor of viewport says that the default viewport settings are:
The default width is 980 pixels. However, these defaults may not work well for your webpages, particularly if you are tailoring your website for a particular device.

[Apple configuring viewport and default values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

Answer (score 1):

## This is the common setting of viewport used in various mobile-optimized websites.

The width property governs the size of the viewport. It is possible to set it to a specific value `(“width=600”)` in terms of CSS pixels. Here it is set to a special value`(“width= device-width”)` which is the width of the device in terms of CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. The initial-scale property governs the zoom level when the page is loaded for the first time.

> Note: The meta tag should be added in the head tag in HTML document.

A Responsive tags has the following attributed:

**width:** Width of the virtual viewport of the device.
**height:** Height of the virtual viewport of the device.
**initial-scale:** Zoom level when the page is first visited.
**minimum-scale:** Minimum zoom level to which a user can zoom the page.
**maximum-scale:** Maximum zoom level to which a user can zoom the page.
**user-scalable:** Flag which allows the device to zoom in or out.(value= yes/no).

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-viewport-meta-tag-for-responsive-web-design/