# I am tring to make my page mobile responsive but it seems like media query does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

So I want to make a quiz game and now I want to make it a little responsive. I made desktop first and now I am making it for pc. I try to use the media query but it seems like it does not work at all. What am I missing?
I tried with a class instead of body but it stil does not work at all.
I excluded the js because it was unnecesary

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600);
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f8f6f0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.question {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.answers {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.answers label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #279;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #38a;
}

.slide {
  position: static;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.active-slide {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.quiz-container {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="QuizTransition.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="previous">Intrebarea precedenta</button>
    <button id="next">Urmatoare intrebare</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="QuizLogic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the [viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your code here in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgyhsc9v/1/).

It looks you made small mistake in `@media query`

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.
Please go through with [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: What was the mistake in OPs media query? The media type (`only screen`) is optional, if that is what you were referring to.

Comment: A more reputable resource: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_types)

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is okey**

> Test with something clear visible. I've using background color, & it's working
>   Use it for more readable- 
>       
>         ...
>         
>         ...

```
The width=device-width key-value pair sets the width of the viewport to the width of the device. 
The initial-scale=1 key-value pair sets the initial zoom level when visiting the page.
```

- Always keep the small scope or  range in down for media query screen size.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600);
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f8f6f0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.question {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.answers {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.answers label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #279;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #38a;
}

.slide {
  position: static;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.active-slide {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.quiz-container {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="QuizTransition.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="previous">Intrebarea precedenta</button>
    <button id="next">Urmatoare intrebare</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="QuizLogic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did, if I put my js it may help?

Comment: because it seems like all changes i do does not reflect

Comment: It should be, make sure you wrote media queries in correct sequence... like- if you choose max-width the write media queries from large width to small. Ex- media (max-width: 400px) after than media (max-width: 600px), for min use vice-versa

Comment: js is not better choise then css for this purpose, share your code which you tried... here my all code is working

Comment: i think i found the problem. I copy paste some querie from internet to test if they work. they work in google chrome but they does not work in my main browser (brave).

Answer (score 0):

When working with width-oriented media queries, It is best to start mobile-first. This means the first portion of your CSS should be styles that are standard for your website and need no media queries at all to work at mobile-width.

Then you would add a media-query starting at a given width using min-width, thus:

```
@media (min-width: 720px) {
  body { background: red;}
}
```

Your media queries have a hole where no declaration covers, but if you need a middle area the syntax looks like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 880px) {
  body { background: pink;}
}
```

I hope that helps.