# understanding the viewport meta tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

this is my understanding of the viewport meta tag.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
the viewport meta tag will set the width of the viewport to the width of
the device. So when the browser renders the page, it will set its dimensions
according to the width of the device and not to the default width which is
980px for many mobile browsers. This implies that the web page should
be rendered in full size without scaling it down.
although that's not what it happens here.
I've created a div with a width of 800px
and when i changed the screen's width to below 800px the page is scaled
down.
I was expecting that i would be scrolling to the right to see the whole
div because it wouldn't fit inside the viewport.
Please can somebody explain why the page was scaled down??
[this is an image of the rendered div with viewport's width > 800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00xlf.png)
[this is an image of the rendered div with viewport's width < 800 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjB7q.png)

this is the code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .container {
            width: 800px;
            border: 5px solid rgb(250, 12, 12);
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>

</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the viewport meta tag really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775195/is-the-viewport-meta-tag-really-necessary)

Comment: basicly, it scales the rendering to the viewport.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of what the viewport meta tag does is correct.

If you've included

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the head of your page, and if the page has an element that is 800px wide, you should have horizontal scrolling on mobile devices.

Here's a comparison of the same page without and with a viewport meta tag.

[image]

Codepen without meta tag:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/QWvBKbZ

Codepen with meta tag:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/mdmjrEq

If your sample page still isn't working for you, double-check your code for typos or share the URL so we can help you out

Comment: I've tested your code on my browser but still got the same problem. It turns out that this problem is related to the responsive mode in chrome itself. I've used Firefox and everything went as expected

Comment: @dalenza, to clarify, are you saying that if you go to https://cdpn.io/panchroma/debug/mdmjrEq/LDAmdnxoQQLr with Chrome and a narrow browser window, you don't see horizontal scrolling?

Comment: the link you provided tells me "this view is expired" so I can't access it on codepen. Here's what I did: I copied your code in vscode and I opened the file in chrome in responsive mode. when I resize the screen the page gets scaled down even with the viewport meta tag.

Comment: If I narrow the browser window there will be horizontal scrolling even without the meta viewport tag,because the viewport will resize to match the window's size in a desktop.

Comment: Thanks @dalenza. I think there's something else at play here that's throwing you off. I don't think that there's a fundamental problem with Chrome itself. One possibility is that you've unintentionally saved a setting in Chrome that is causing issues. If you're able to save your code to a publicly accessible URL, please share the address and I'll continue trying to help you out.