# I would like to have a CSS layout with 100% body height

Tags: css, height, sticky-footer

I've been making some great progress so far. I have the sticky footer working the way I would like i.e.

If there is little content show a footer on the screen. If there is lots of content push it down :)

So what I'm trying to do Is to have a nice little border around my body content, until it reaches the footer :)

Alas I've not been able to do that and I've only been able to make it do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dcf104/ZQEGw/

```
Can you adise me on some additional code?
Maybe I need some extra <divs>?
```

You can see the red sides only go so far...

How can I make them go all the way to the footer?

Many Thanks, and your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Set .page-wrap like that:

```
.page-wrap {
      margin-bottom: -180px;
      height: 100%;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQEGw/1/

Comment: The one problem with this is that when you then have long content it goes behind the footer :( http://jsfiddle.net/dcf104/ZQEGw/14/

Answer (score 0):

This [article describes a sticky footer](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page):

- with little content show footer on the screen - i assume you mean at the end of the viewport ([what is the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939693/what-is-view-port-in-html),[article about viewport](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html))
- push the footer down if content fills the viewport

You can take a [look at the gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8166407) or the **[example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kglhu)**

The CSS

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
#container { min-height:100%; position:relative; }
#header { background:#ff0; padding:10px; }
#body { padding:10px; padding-bottom:60px;  /* Height of the footer */ }
#footer { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:60px;         
            /* Height of the footer */ background:#6cf; }
```

The basic html structure

```
   <div id=container>
     <div id=header>
     </div>
     <div id=body>
     </div>
     <div id=footer>
     </div>
   </div>
```