# clarification of css width calculation

Tags: html, css, viewport-units, css-calc

By trial and error, I calculated the width of a header block:

```
width: calc(100% - 96px);
width: calc(100vw - 112px);
```

Both (seem to) produce the same result.  I read [how width is defined](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/width-and-height-of-elements-in-css) and want to check that I understand this.  I have:

- html element with margin: 0, padding: 0
- body element with margin: 0, padding: 10px, border: 2px
- page wrapper element (#page, inside body) with margin: 0, padding: 10px, border: 4px
- header element (inside #page) with margin:0, padding: 20px, border: 2px

With the % calculation, I subtracted 2 x (total of the above padding and borders).

The result places my header exactly as I would like: centered inside the parent #page wrapper,  extending from the left to right edges within the padding.  This is because:

- it places it +48 pixels in from the left edge
- adds 100% of the body width (as above)
- then removes 48 pixels from the left edge + 48 pixels from the right edge

Am I correct in this?

Secondly, for the vw calculation, why do I need to subtract an extra 16 pixels?

My question isn't so much the viewport width itself (I don't know JS yet, but I read [how to get the viewport widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939693/what-is-viewport-in-html)).  The calculation works on different browsers/devices.

The full code is on CodePen: https://codepen.io/necrohell/pen/rNYBepm?editors=0100

Comment: 100vw include the scrollbar width

Comment: @TemaniAfif But,for example, Safari on iPhone doesn’t have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Body width cut       => (10px X 2)padding + (2px X 2)border = 24px

#page container cut  => (10px X 2)padding + (4px X 2)border = 28px

Total = 52px + header's own padding and border (20px X 2 + 2px X 2 = 44)

= 96px (total)

I think you missed header's own padding and border. When "box-sizing" property of the container element is not "border-box" then padding and border are excluded from the width.

Secondly, for the vw calculation, that extra 16 pixels is because of the scrollbar as the scrollbar is included in the 100vw.

Comment: If you have scrollbars enabled, that is. Non-windows devices have that as their default.

Answer (score -1):

```
vw -    Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*
% -     Relative to the parent element

* Viewport = the browser window size. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw = 0.5cm.
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php

If you have a parent element with a set width of 300px, using "100%" will have a max width of 300px. Whereas if you use "vw", it goes off the size of the screen. The layout will drastically change from screen to screen and devices. Open your code from your phone to see the change I mean.